# Confusion about how to insert database using XmlHttpRequest object

Tags: asp.net, database, xmlhttprequest

everybody.I am trying to learn how to use `XmlHttpRequest` object and look for some examples on the net .I have found this code below and made some changes .Then create a table  and added single  field  called "name"with value varchar .Everything seemed ok .But When i exacute that code I have notice that nothing inserted to the database.So I am wondering is that  something wrong or missing in this code or any problem with database I have created .I have no idea

```
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function XmlHttpObj() {
            var xhr = null;
            // Tarayıcımızın ActiveXObject desteği olup olmadığını kontrol ediyoruz.
            // İnternet Explorer'da gerçekleştirmek için Microsoft.XMLHTTP
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("MsXml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
                try {
                    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e) {
                    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
                        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                }
            }
            return xhr;
        }
        var talep = XmlHttpObj();
        function Listen() {
            if (talep.readyState == 4 && talep.status == 200) {
                var sonuc = talep.responseText;
                if (sonuc != null) {
                    alert("Kayıt Eklendi");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Hata Meydana Geldi");
                }
            }
        }
        //veritabanına ürün ekleme yapacağımız fonksiyon
        //onreadystatechange ile durum değişikliği kontrolü yaptık.
        function Ekle() {
            talep.open("POST", "Webform1.aspx");
            talep.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            talep.onreadystatechange = Listen;
            talep.send("mail=" + document.all.Text1.value);
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
<input id="Text1" type="text" /><br />
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Ürün Ekle" onclick="Ekle()"/>
```

And this is aspx.cs file

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["mail"]))
{
    try
    {
        //SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("server=.\\sqlexpress;database=northwind;trusted_connection=true");
        //SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("insert into productss (name) values (@ad)", sqlcon);
        //sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad", Request.Form["mail"]);
        //sqlcon.Open();
        //sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //sqlcon.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you do not use `XmlHttpRequest` directly. It has many complexities and it is very difficult to get it to work on all browsers. I would recommend using PageMethods. It can be done using a `ScriptManager` or, better yet, using jQuery. For a good article about the latter, see this: [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)